# Bot sends his prefix when mentioned in Command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want that if someone tags the bot, he will return his prefix
but when someone tags him on a command for example `!kick @bot#1234` he wont send his prefix.
Ive done a command on on_command that returns the prefix, but when someone tags him on a command he responding his prefix.

Comment: Do you mean `prefix`?

Comment: Yes I ment prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) event

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content in [f'<@!{bot.user.id}>', f'<@{bot.user.id}>']:
        await message.channel.send(f'My prefix is `{bot.command_prefix}`')

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```